# GRANT ROLE TO USER in MySQL

Tags: mysql, permissions, mysql-5.6, role

I created one role `QI_RO`, granted all privileges on all schemas on the server and I was trying to grant role privilege to another user but throwing error.

```
GRANT QI_RO to test_user@'%';
```

Error Message:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'QI_RO to test_user@'%'' at line 1
```

DB version:

```
mysql> select version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 5.6.10    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

How to grant role privileges to users in Mysql like other databases, Postgres and oracle?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is only supported in  mysql 8 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/roles.html

Comment: So is there any other solution to do in v5.6?

Comment: i doubt that, we ask a long time for this. check out ldap plugin https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/pluggable-authentication.html